# Java String function help needed

Tags: java, arrays, string, function

I have a homework question from college that I am having trouble with and I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on where to go with it. We are using Arrays, for loops, if else and Strings.

I have to create a programme to take in a number of peoples names then put them in an Array ( which I had no problem with) I then need to separate the names in the array according to the first letters of each name : A-G in one array, letters H-P in another and the rest in a final array.

I have been told to use a String Function for this but not to use lists or Char. 
This is the code I have so far :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Party {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // declaring scanner

   int numGuests; // declaring the variable for number of guests
    System.out.println("please enter the number of guests you are hosting : ");
    numGuests = sc.nextInt(); // scanner for user inout num of guests

    String[] names = new String[numGuests]; // string for number of guests

    System.out.println("Please enter names "); 

    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) // for loop for inputing the names.
    {
        names[i] = sc.next();
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: This is not a question and doesnt belong here.

Comment: you haven't try to separate names .try your self first.

Comment: Well its off topic... but still to send you in right direction... so for string charAt(0) this will give 1st chracter and on the basis of it you can sort them...

Comment: That looks like nice code.  What is your question?

Comment: You could also go for matches and some regex, if your task does allow it.

Comment: @mikeb my question is what type of String function should I use to separate the array in the simplest way ?

Comment: I'd put chars A-G in one array and H-P in another, create 2 arrays for your results and loop over your input.  Get the first character (charAt(0), as suggested).  If the charAt(0) exists in one array or the other put it in the appropriate list.

Comment: @mikeb thank you. I used the charAt and it seems to be working grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please Use below logic and get result according to your requirement..
package com.test;
public class Namessplite {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] names={"ABC","CAD","JKL","MNO"}; // these are names for example
    String[] atog_group = new String[10];
    String[] gtopgroup=  new String[10];
    int j=0,k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if((int)names[i].charAt(0)<72 && (int)names[i].charAt(0)>64){
            atog_group[j]=names[i];
            j++;
        }else{
            gtopgroup[k]=names[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A TO G Names Are :: ");
        for(int m=0;m<j;m++){
            System.out.println(atog_group[m]);  
        }
                System.out.println("G TO P Names Are :: ");
        for(int m=0;m<k;m++){
            System.out.println(gtopgroup[m]);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you change case of letters i.e lower case charge 72 as 68 and 64 as 60

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Style:

```
private static void splitNamesToArray(String[] names) {

    String[] aToG = Arrays.stream(names).filter(n -> n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) >= 65 && n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) <= 71).toArray(String[]::new);
    String[] hToP = Arrays.stream(names).filter(n -> n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) >= 72 && n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) <= 80).toArray(String[]::new);
    String[] rest = Arrays.stream(names).filter(n -> n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) >= 81 && n.toUpperCase().charAt(0) <= 90).toArray(String[]::new);

    System.out.println("A to G: " + Arrays.toString(aToG));
    System.out.println("H to P: " + Arrays.toString(hToP));
    System.out.println("Rest: " + Arrays.toString(rest));
}
```